# О шейдерах в DirectX11

Tags: directx

Ворос из области любознательности.
 В 9-м шейдеры были еще вроде как "приятным дополнением". В SDK-примере, в функции рендеринга закомментировал шейдеринг и при запуске проги у меня  на время отрубилась видюха. Естественно напросился вопрос:

В DirectX11 установка шейдеров обязательна или нет?

Comment: хз, но судя по реакции твоей карты, то да, наверное. разберись в программе сначала, потом задавай вопросы.

Comment: @pol500 "Реакция" карты?!

Comment: Ну в общем-то как бы и разобрался в общих чертах. Там собственно разбираться не в чем - вывод одного несчастного двухмерного полигона. С начала идёт загрузка и инициализация атрибутов шейдеров,создани буфера и прочие его бла-бла-бла, а в рендеринге собственно всё в кучу сводим. Ни хотим, что-то не сводим. Буфер вершин же не запрещено не выводить. Хотя на понимание могло сказаться поняите из DirectX9. Ну в общем котик ответил на вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с `Direct3D 10`, `fixed pipeline` больше [не поддерживается,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/cc308047) все осуществляется через шейдера. Это же утверждение, естественно, справедливо и для 11 версии `Direct3D`.

> - Direct3D 10 no longer supports the fixed-function transform and lighting pipeline.
> - Direct3D 10 no longer supports the fixed-function texture blender (sometimes called a fixed-function *pixel shader*).